# Jetpack Compose - Nested Navigation and Lifetime/Disposing only on parent route?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm attempting to create a navigation that looks something like this

```
LoginRoute

ChatRoomListRoute

ChatRoomRoute
    |
    -- Chat room (where you write messages, read messages, etc)
    -- Room details (self explanatory)
    -- Room settings (self explanatory)
    -- Etc
```

Here is a drawing of what I mean;

[image]
As it currently stands, in my `ChatRoomRoute`

```kotlin
composable("room" + "/{roomId}") { navBackStackEntry ->
  val roomId = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("roomId")

  /* do stuff */
  DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    onDispose {
      chatRoom.dispose()
    }
  }
}

composable("roomdetails" + "/{roomId}", { navBackStackEntry ->
  val roomId = navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("roomId")
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Is there some functionality that allows the application to go from `ChatRoomRoute` to a "child path" like, `Room Details` *without* having the `DisposableEffect` run? Essentially I want the `ChatRoomRoute` to be a parent node, and only when the user leaves that specific chat room, the data in it, gets disposed of. Currently, I've added the `Room Details` as `composable` in the nav host controller, but that makes the disposable effect run, when the user navigates to `Room Details` from within the chat room, which is not what I want.

The reason why I want this, is because when the user stops browsing a room, it should destroy some FFI-bound resources, but I don't want it to do it unnecessarily.

Comment: Correct, `DisposableEffect` is not useful in your case. When using Compose navigation `ViewModel`s are scoped to the `NavBackStackEntry`, so usually using a `ViewModel` to manage state is the way to go. But if in your case, you can not rely on `ViewModel.onCleared()` method for disposal for some reason, you could track navigation changes in the root/parent with [getBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavGraphNavigator#getBackStack()) and dispose resources when a specific screen leaves the navigation backstack.